# Can we ask questions and answer them by our self?

Tags: discussion

Can we ask questions and answer them, if we believe that other people may refer to them in the future?

Is it ethical to do this to get better reputation in this community?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350585/how-do-sites-moderate-self-answered-questions

Comment: @StephenRauch from what i understood from your link is that we can do that but not in spammy way, and experts have a big margin in this practice, right?

Comment: Self answers are allowed, but are often of poor quality.  Site Experts are more likely to understand what makes a high quality question and/or answer.

Comment: There is a dedicated section in the [help], [Can I answer my own question?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) Did you check it?

Comment: Although infrequent, there does exist an award for such action (implying that it is sanctioned by the site). However, as others have mentioned, this behavior is likely highly discouraged as higher quality answers may likely be given by others (although not always!)

Comment: Thank you @ethan.